# react-native link adds compile to gradle script, but compile support soon gone

Tags: react-native, hyperlink, compilation

Whenever I use react-native link, it adds the following to my app gradle file.

[Image from Android Studio Gradle File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj67o.png)
Then when I compile this, Android Studio tells me that "compile" is being deprecated and won't be supported after 2018. My question is, what would the correct replacement be for, for instance, react-native-ionicons?

The section of the gradle file in question is as follows.

```
dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to `react-native link` not having been updated but as of `React-Native 0.58.3` the linking procedure has been updated so that  `compile` and `api` have been replaced with `implementation`. Which you can see at this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/20853)

You could also just change `compile` to `implementation` in your grade file.

However you may find that some of the `build.gradle` files for the dependencies still use `compile` and `api`, unfortunately they only way to fix warnings from those is to make a pull request on the dependency changing `compile` and `api` to `implementation`

Comment: This is not correct. This is due to the fact that `react-native link` had not been updated to use `implementation` and `api` instead of `compile`. This was only done under [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/20853) pull request, which has not yet been released at the time of writing - pending release [v0.58.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/4dfdec9b28074b311ffd75084d9d2a3cbd41a800). The question refers to the user's own `build.gradle` file, and not that of the dependency being used.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for that :)